# Is iOS 4.3 with armv7 the lowest you can go if you want to support iPhone 5?

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-5

I read on the internet that iOS 4.3 with armv7 is the lowest you can go if you want to support iPhone 5. So, if I want my app to run on iPhone 5, then do I need to set the deployment target as iOS 4.3 and set the architecture as armv7?

I couldn't find an official documentation for this. Could you correct this information if it's wrong?

**UPDATE:** I've found the answer in the [Xcode 4.5 GM seed Release Notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_4.5_gm_seed/xcode_45_gm_seed_rn.pdf) documentation of Apple:

Changes in Xcode 4.5:

> **- Support removed for armv6**
> Xcode 4.5 and later does not support generating armv6 binaries.
>
> **- Minimum supported deployment target is iOS 4.3**
> The minimum supported deployment target with Xcode 4.5 or later is iOS 4.3

Comment: Mike's approach here sounds like a potential solution for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12678077/19679

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any official statement on this, but it's pretty clear if you take a look at Xcode 4.5. It's also a logical step forward as last armv6 device (iPhone 3G) has been out of sale for over two years and without software updates for almost two years as well.

**Note:** as of posting this answer, an unofficial way to support both armv6 and armv7s has been found here: [How to support both armv6 and armv7s for release build in xcode 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12619124/877465)

Comment: OK, I've edited my question with a link to the official documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is only half the truth;
the other half is you can actually do combine an iOS 4.0/armv6 build into your iOS6/armv7(s) build.

This process is described here:
[How to support both armv6 and armv7s for release build in xcode 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619124/how-to-support-both-armv6-and-armv7s-for-release-build-in-xcode-4-5)