# Submitting iPhone5 app with Xcode 4.4.1

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, armv6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is iOS 4.3 with armv7 the lowest you can go if you want to support iPhone 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400968/is-ios-4-3-with-armv7-the-lowest-you-can-go-if-you-want-to-support-iphone-5)

I have modified my iOS app for iPhone 'GiraffeMode' and tested it with xcode 4.5. Everything is OK. I still need to support armv6 which was dropped from xcode 4.5, so I built app with xcode 4.4.1 and submitted it into the App Store. App passed validation and was submitted successfully. But same moment I've got email from iTunes Store:

> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   %name of app%. To process your delivery, the following issues must be
>   corrected: 
> **Invalid Launch Image** - You app contains a launch image with
>   a size modifier that is only supported for apps built with the iOS 6.0
>   SDK or later.

Does it mean I have to make choice between armv6 and iPhone5 'GiraffeMode'? Is there any way choose both?

Comment: sorry, but what is GiraffeMode?

Comment: I believe he means the longer display.

Comment: In particular, you might want to read Mike's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12678077/19679 that I link to in a comment on the above question.